# Problema con los Cors Spring Boot y Angular 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular, cors

Estoy usando una `Api Rest` con `Spring boot` con una basic auth de `spring` security, Al hacer la petición al backend con Angular me da como resultado un problema con los `Cors` `login:

> 1 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api/alumno/loginAlumno: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Os dejo como esta las configuraciones.

1. Estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Código del WebSecurityConfig (basic auth de spring security)

   ```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @Configuration
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
           http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().and()
                   .csrf().disable();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Código del CorsFiltes.

   ```
   @Component
   @Configuration
   public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

       private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorsFilter.class);

       public CorsFilter() {
           log.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
       }

       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
           HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                   "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, authorization, x-auth-token");

           if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
               response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
           } else {
               chain.doFilter(req, res);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
       }

       @Override
       public void destroy() {
       }

   }
   ```
4. Configuración de las cabeceras en angular (Servicio de login)

   ```
   @Injectable()
   export class LoginService {

       private url = environment.REST_API_URL;
       private headers;
       private options;

       constructor(public http: Http) {
           this.headers = new Headers({
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
               'Authorization': 'Basic dXNlcjpwcm9fR2FjZTIwMTg=',
           })

       }

       loguearAlumno(personaLoguear) {
           //Peticion al backend
           return this.http.post(this.url + 'alumno/loginAlumno', JSON.stringify(personaLoguear),
               { headers: this.headers }).map(res => res.json());

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El servidor al que se envía la solicitud POST debe incluir el encabezado `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Esto se debe a que depende del servidor especificar que acepta solicitudes de origen cruzado y que permite el encabezado de solicitud de tipo de contenido, etc. Rl cliente no puede decidir por sí mismo que un servidor determinado debe permitir CORS.

Un ejemplo puede ser como este:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 
"my-authorized-proxy-or-domain");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
"Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese mismo problema lo solucioné poniendo la etiqueta

> @Cors

sobre las clases que publicaban la API desde Spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que en la sentencia:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, authorization, x-auth-token");
```

No está el *header* `Cache-Control`.

Por otro lado, y como solución más general y permanente: ¿Has pensando en usar la opción de proxy inverso del servidor de angular? Te evitará todos los problemas de CORS.

Answer (score 0):

En el metodo **corsConfigurer** realice esos cambios para acceder a los controladores o rescontroles desde angular a **Spring boot** , **Spring security**

```
 package com.sisteds.boot.security;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @CrossOrigin(origins= "*")
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("loginserv")
        private LoginServ loginserv;


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(loginserv);
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

                }           

            };          
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            super.configure(web);
        }



        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{       
            http.cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/logout").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST"))
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
            .authorizeRequests().and()      
            .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable();
        }




    }
```